# How to set git bash? So that I can use it from any location

Tags: git, git-bash

Git bash is installed in my system but when I try to open it, it says application not found.

However I can open it from a specific location (E drive):
[image: Git bash context menu]

Other than that specific location I am not able to open it.

Comment: Maybe you are accessing an older version or something? Have you tried reinstalling a current version? Opening Git Bash works for me. Do you have information about your Computer and OS for us? Which Git for Windows version?

Comment: git version 2.17.1.windows.2, computer os  Microsoft Windows 11 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its silent upgrade leaving out all the customized options. So, the solution is to delete the current crippled installation, and reinstall Git manually, with manual selection of "Git Bash Here" features.